# How can I obtain Steam achievements in Torchlight after "finishing" the main story? 

Tags: achievements, steam, torchlight

I finished the main story of Torchlight way before Steam introduced [achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/Torchlight/achievements). Now I have my Level 50 character and am doing quests.

Is the only way to get some of the achievements (such as "Over the Brink", etc.) for events occurring in the main story to replay it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, replaying the story is the only way to earn the acheivements.

I was in this situation myself, but I used the special function to "retire" my character, so at least I had bonuses with my new one.

Comment: There is an other way. You could try the "Steam Achievment Manager" (3rd party software) which allow you to manually unlock any achievment in steam games (potentially VAC-risky). Though, i don't remember it being legal, so i won't be posting a link here. Google it yourself.

Comment: @Lysarion Seeing as it is legal and you cannot be VAC-banned for it, here it is: [Steam Achievement Manager](http://gib.me/sam/).

Comment: @ArdaXi - Is it _really_ legal? Are you sure? Is there some official source?

Comment: Oh, also then there's the question of "what's the point of 'achieving' achievements by using an editor.' :/

Comment: @ver Legality has nothing to do with it. The TOS doesn't disallow it either. I can't give you an official source because they don't **condone** it, but they can't detect it either.